# Understanding and repairing kitchen shelf door based on a gas spring

Tags: kitchens, rivets

From my understanding, a gas spring has more or less unlimited life. However, in our kitchen (1) which is by now more than 10 years old, a kitchen shelf door using two [250N gas springs](https://www.amazon.de/Original-Gasdruckd%C3%A4mpfer-Gasdruckfeder-Kompressionsfeder-Kesseb%C3%B6hmer/dp/B00U670ZGG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1544103345&sr=8-1&keywords=gasfeder%20250n) seems to get old: the springs can't hold the door and it slides down back.

Now please tell me if in the following construction it could be possible to remove and exchange the gas spring which is sold separately or I need to replace the "whole thing"(2) because of the rivets.

[image]

(1) the kitchen is of an unknown vendor

(2) I will add the image with the flip side to show the rivets but maybe there is a name for this type of the appliance "metal-frame-with-two-springs" so that I could google for its availability as well.

Comment: `a gas spring has more or less unlimited life` .... not true

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this YouTube video answers the question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rp8365lEGjY

You have to release metal clips at both spring's ends to release it, and the new spring can just click in.

German name for the whole appliance is "*Hochschwenkbeschlag*", no idea how to call it in English.

Answer (score 1):

That looks incredibly similar to "hydraulic trunk lifts" for cars.

You should be able to detach it at both ends and install a replacement.